# Как наложить иконку на button? Android

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-sdk

Нужно сделать как здесь [image: клик]

Получается что это иконка на кнопке

Comment: Как вы поняли что это кнопка? Я вижу обычный слой с рамкой и несколькими элементами внутри.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17258393/7566397

Comment: @AndreyMihalev ну, в ТЗ написано что это кнопка, ну может не кнопка, но примерно нужно сделать так.

Comment: Ну и покажите что вы сделали уже и что не получилось!?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать элемент ImageButton у которого имеется атрибут с путем к изображению, вместо Button.

Comment: Вариант не рабочий.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать для кнопки атрибут `background`, в который можно поместить изображение которое должно быть на кнопке.

Посмотрите ещё [здесь](https://android-tools.ru/coding/delaem-krasivye-knopki-v-android/). (может найдёте что-нибудь)